# Google Chrome input type="date"

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have almost no knowledge of web programming, but I have been tasked to solve something on my company's website.  Apparently, I have an issue with browsers using HTML5 on a legacy site using type="date" and I need to find a way around it.

My site has a lot of date fields that the user must input like such:

```
 <input type="date" name="DateStart" size="15" value="8/30/2011">
```

In every browser we currently use except Chrome, this works just fine. Chrome is the only browser that supplies rolling buttons to scroll through the date.  What I see on the back end of this is an attempt to do this:

```
FormatDateTime(DateStart, 2)
```

I get an invalid date error which means that we cannot use Chrome to fill out this form. Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chrome does not have issues with date-inputs, [you are using the wrong date-format](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/infrastructure.html#global-dates-and-times), sir. Chrome isn't the only browser until today which has support for the new HTML5 inputs. Opera for example displays a dropdown with a calendar on inputs with `type="date"`.

Also the size-attribute does not exist on HTML5-date-inputs.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry I worded it that way.  As I said, I have almost no knowledge of web dev.  This site is about 10 or so years old and the company has no budget to replace it so I have been tasked with keeping it current.  Is there a way to keep Chrome from using HTML5 in this specific instance and go back to the way it used to work?  It was working fine until version 9 or so.

Comment: I fixed my original wording to be less offensive.

Comment: The problem here is, that your/the site used an input-type of "date" long before it was included in any standards-draft. If you can just witch the type to "text", that would be the simplest solution.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Thankfully, the dev wrote in a hidden for the date field that matters for queries to the database.  Hopefully, I won't have to fix that disaster. :)

Answer (score 29):

Actually chrome's support for 'date' *is* broken.  ([See here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=79064)).  At least for the moment.

The use of 'date' in the HTML is absolutely fine - browser's which do not know of or support an input type are supposed to fallback to type='text'.

Currently chrome partially supports date, in a way that is essentially broken (it adds a couple of up-down buttons, but no datepicker.)

Of course you do need to bear in mind that if you *are* using type='date', [and if the browser supports it](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/), then you'll want to disable whatever datepicker support you'd otherwise be using.

**UPDATE (6 Feb 2012):**

It looks to me like this is now fixed.  Chrome no longer claims to support input type='date', and does not provide the partially complete implementation.

**UPDATE (17 Aug 2012):**

Chrome *does* now have [input type="date" support](https://plus.google.com/102860501900098846931/posts/hTcMLVNKnec), and it's more functional this time.

Comment: In fact [the WHATWG spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#date-state-(type=date)) does not mention how the UI should look like, just that there have to be some "control" to insert or alter the date. This is usually a datepicker but as of the spec it hasn't to be. So "broken" depends on the point of view. I've seen people using the original Chrome date input with a mouse scroll wheel (which does work – scroll up above the input to increase the date). I know it's a poor implementation – but not broken, as it is somehow usable.

Comment: @feeela The current implementation is much more functional that previously.  The previous implementation was basically unusable, as demonstrated by the fact that the team later chose to remove it.

Comment: And I would prefer any of the popular javascript datepickers over the half assed chrome attempt.

Answer (score 6):

The value field for the input type = input needs to be in the format yyyy-MM-dd.  [Check the W3 standards on this.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.value)

This means you must do something like DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd").  in your code, I would suggest a custom HtmlHelper.

The format of the date in the browser is completely dependent on your system settings.

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks! <input type="date" id="OrderDate" name="OrderDate" value="@Model.OrderDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />

Answer (score 1):

Use this date format : `date("Y-m-d");`