# calendar bug in chrome browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, calendar

This is a simple form. Users follow the order typing their name and select their sex. when they click the calendar button, the calendar will show up and hide again. It only appear in google chrome calendar. I have two computers,and I updated two browser to ver 83.0.4103.116. One computer has this error, so I don't know who can see this error in their computer? How can I solve this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
         <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="name:"/><br>
        <select name="shops" >
            <option value="0" selected="selected">sex</option>
            <option value="MALE">MALE</option>
            <option value="FEMALE">FEMALE</option>  
        </select><br>                                               
       <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
  <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
     <br> 

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your Chrome to Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit).
Clean your cache or temporary files

```
1. Ctrl + R
2. %temp% press Enter
```

If problem persists, please reinstall chrome to it's latest version

Comment: yes! Chrome Version is 83.0.4103.116 which I wrote in the description and the window 10 is new setup no cache and temporary files in there.

Comment: It's not producing in all systems,  you can try by reinstalling the chrome.

Comment: I reinstall an old version chrome, and it don't have this problem. when i upgrade to version 83.0.4103.116, the problem appear again. why the another computer no this problem?

Comment: <form>
 <input type="date" id="testInput">
 <input type="button" id="testButton" value="Test support"
  onclick="
alert((document.getElementById('testInput').type=='date')?'supported':'unsupported')">
</form>        try this code and run on your chrome to ensure it is supported or not.    https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=79064

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243381/google-chrome-input-type-date     check this one too